# s:iterator over list of map

Tags: jsp, struts, ognl

I have a list of map - `listMaps List<Map<String,Object>>`
and I wanted to use a `s:iterator` to build an image source dynamically using specific key values

I have tried the following but i am not getting any results

```
<s:iterator value="lastMaps" var="listMap" status="st">  
    test 1 <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/image/%{#listMap.key}.jpg" />
    test 2 <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/image/%{'lastMaps['+#st.index+'].key'}.jpg" />
    test 3 <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/image/%{top['key']}.jpg" />
</s:iterator>
```

I have looked at what gets parsed in firebug and i see that any text inside `%{''}` is not being evaluated - not even a simple text

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/image/<s:property value="%{#listMap.key}"/>".jpg" />`

And so on - basicly, you forgot s:property tag which evaluates.

Comment: you just saved my day, just remove the double quote before the '.jpg' and it works great